# Recover HDD after creating USB installer

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, usb-drive, data-recovery

I just mistakingly used the wrong device to create a USB installer for Ubuntu. I wanted to use my flash drive which was disk1 and ended up using disk2 which was my external HD. Is there any way I can recover the information?

**EDIT:** well I'm getting this:

[image]

Guess this means I'm doomed right? Those are the biggest partitions which means they're the ones I want to recover.

Answer (score 0):

First don't use the drive to install or transfer any data onto there.

Run testdisk and follow the instructions to recover your partition

Comment: Can you give me some pointers? I had 2 partitions on the disk, one was for general backups between my mac and PC and the other was my Time Machine.

Comment: you will have to do it one at a time. You won't be rewriting any data, just the same sectors as they were before. For a windows partition you will have to search under Intel/PC partition, unless its formatted as GPT, and for mac choose apple. sudo testdisk>create log file>choose your partition>allow it time to scan the entire hard drive> select which to restore. Also I would erase the linux partition before running testdisk and it will pop up when searching so just don't select it.

Comment: I get a message that my partitions can't be recovered

Comment: Are there any other options?